# Java Exception Catch / Throw

Tags: java, exception

I have the following classes:

**BusinessException.java** (Is the main exception class that needs to catch the exception and throw it)

```
public class BusinessException
    extends Exception
{
 private BusinessExceptionInfo faultInfo
 public BusinessException(String message, BusinessExceptionInfo faultInfo) {
        super(message);
        this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
    }
 public BusinessException(String message, BusinessExceptionInfo faultInfo, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
 }

 public BusinessExceptionInfo getFaultInfo() {
        return faultInfo;
    }
}
```

**BusinessExceptionInfo.java**

```
public class BusinessException {

    protected ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse;
    protected String message;

    // getters and setters for these properties
}
```

**ExceptionResponse.java** (This class holds the exception messages and stack trace. This class needs to populated with the values coming from exception)

```
public class ExceptionResponse {

    protected String exceptionClass;
    protected String exceptionMessage;
    protected List<ErrorResponseItem> errorResponseItems;
    protected String stackTrace;

    // getters and setters for these properties
}
```

**ErrorResponseItem.java**

```
public class ErrorResponseItem {

    protected String defaultErrorDescription;
    protected List<String> descriptionVariables;
    protected String errorCode;
    protected SourceSystemFault sourceSystemFault;

// getter and setter methods
}

// SourceSystemFault.java
public class SourceSystemFault {

    protected List<String> calloutParameters;
    protected String errorCode;
    protected String errorDescription;
    protected String operationName;
    protected String serviceName;
    protected String system;
}
```

**MyClass.java** (My class is where in I need to check and throw it. How can I pass the exception message, stack trace to ExceptionResponse from this class?)
Can any one share an example of similar issue. This will be helpful. I got to work with these file to handle exceptions in my project.

```
public MyResponse myMethod(MyRequest req)
            throws BusinessException {
}
```

How can I catch and throw the BusinessException. I am a newbie and need help.

Comment: Could you explain us what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to throw business exception in a soap webservice

Comment: Have you read the Java exception tutorials? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/ Where is the exception intended to be caught? What do you want to happen when you get an exception?